# Windows Media creation tool not running

Tags: windows, windows-10

I was using Windows media creation tool and had to force close it. Now my Windows Media creation tool is not running and ask to restart my pc to fix this issue but restarting doesn't fix it.

So i tried to delete system files (temporary windows installation file). But its not deleting

> Here's What i am doing
>
> C: properties > Disk Clean Up > Clean System files > Checked all options in the menu and clicked and clicked OK

Then its shows deleting files and after its done. There is no space freed in the drive and when i check again with disk clean up all files are there to delete.

Comment: Look for hidden folder named C:\$Windows.~ws. If it exists, try deleting it. This is where MCT stores its temporary files during download.

Comment: Unable to delete. Says its in use but i have checked media creation tool is not running

Comment: Try booting in Safe Mode and retry deleting. Moreover are you using MCT to download Windows 10 ISO for example? In that case you can directly download the ISO using the official MS Tech Bench site at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

Comment: @pat2015 will this link provide me latest build?